# How to query a simple epoch-based partition column in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I do not know the primary key while querying in Cassandra.
All I know is the time range for which I want to get the data.
So I have kept the partition key of my table as the epoch.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp2 (
    epoch bigint,
    primary key (epoch)
);

INSERT INTO tmp2 (epoch) values (unixTimestampOf(now()));
INSERT INTO tmp2 (epoch) values (unixTimestampOf(now()));
INSERT INTO tmp2 (epoch) values (unixTimestampOf(now()));
INSERT INTO tmp2 (epoch) values (unixTimestampOf(now()));
INSERT INTO tmp2 (epoch) values (unixTimestampOf(now()));


select * from tmp2;
 epoch
---------------
 9410
 8171
 7595
 8746
 6009
```

Note: I have reduced the epochs to more readable numbers here by getting rid of the common prefix 148826477

I try to query this table based on epoch range:

```
Select * from tmp2 where epoch >= 6009 and epoch <= 7595;
InvalidRequest: Only EQ and IN relation are supported on the partition key (unless you use the token() function)
```

So I use the token() function and all is good:

```
Select * from tmp2 where token(epoch) <= token(6009) and token(epoch) >= token(7595);
 epoch
---------------
 7595
 8746
 6009
```

However, I am suspicious that using token is not actually giving me querying based on time because token(epoch) and token(epoch+100) might not have same linear relationship as epoch and epoch+100 have.
Example:

```
Select * from tmp2 where token(epoch) <= token(7009) and token(epoch) >= token(7595);

 epoch
-------
(0 rows)
```

1. Is there a way to query the epoch based partition column in chunks of 1-minute? OR
2. Is there a way to get rid of the milliseconds and seconds in the epoch while storing the data, so that the epoch's resolution is only a minute and I can specify the partition easily for minutes?

Comment: Do you know the minute, when the data inserted ?

Comment: I was hoping to convert the epoch into minute within the CQL itself. Something like `INSERT INTO tmp2 (epoch) values (setResolutionToLastMinute(now()))`. Does CQL have something that will reduce the resolution of now() to a minute?

Answer (score 0):

> However, I am suspicious that using token is not actually giving me
>   querying based on time because token(epoch) and token(epoch+100) might
>   not have same linear relationship as epoch and epoch+100 have.

Your suspicious are right. They are absolutely two very different things indeed. I [recently posted explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39840707/6570821) about the difference between querying by data and querying by the token function.

Back to your questions:

1. No, there's no way to perform such task, unless your partition key is *already* at 1-minute granularity
2. No, you have to *round* it on your client side code and insert it into your timestamp column.

If you just follow [my advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42481524/6570821) on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42476481/6570821) you'd solve in a blink of a eye.

I wish to add that a fundamental thing in cassandra is **you really need to know the partition key when querying data**, this is what the error says.